# Bootstrap Collapse Error: SyntaxError: The string did not match the expected pattern

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to use a Bootstrap 5 Collapse. This same code has been copied from a similar page, but the rows do not expand to show the collapsed (hidden) row. Instead I get the above error on the browser console.

The browser's console has these lines at the bottom ( I can click the top row to expand the remaining rows, which looks like the attached pic):

```
SyntaxError: The string did not match the expected pattern.
querySelector - index.js:64
e - index.js:64
(anonymous function) - collapse.js:317
```

[image]

If I tap any of the lines after the `f` symbols, the browser redirects me to the "Sources" tab to the relevant JS file for Bootstrap.

The code is - not the full page, this is exerted:

```
<?php
    $x = 1;
    $leadingScore = -100;
    if (isset($leaderboard)) {
        foreach ($leaderboard as $score) {
            $pid = (string) $score['playerId'];
?>

            <div class="collapse">
                <tr data-bs-toggle='collapse' data-bs-target='#<?=$pid?>'>
                    <th scope="row">
                        <?php 
                            if ($leadingScore != $score['score'])
                                echo $x;
                                            
                        ?>
                    </th>

                    <td style="text-align: left;">

                        <?php echo $score['playerName']." (".$score['hcap'].")"; ?>
                                        
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php 
                            echo $score['score'];
                            $leadingScore = $score['score'];
                        ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php 
                            echo $score['thru'];
                        ?>
                    </td>                                       
                </tr>
                
                <tr id='<?=$pid?>' class='collapse'>
                                        
                    <td colspan=4>
                        <table class='table'>
                            <tr>
                                <th class='sub-th' scope='col'></th>
                                <th class='sub-th' scope='col'>1</th>
                                <th class='sub-th' scope='col'>2</th>
                                <th class='sub-th' scope='col'>3</th>
                                <th class='sub-th' scope='col'>4</th>
                                <th class='sub-th' scope='col'>5</th>
                                <th class='sub-th' scope='col'>6</th>
                                <th class='sub-th' scope='col'>7</th>
                                <th class='sub-th' scope='col'>8</th>
                                <th class='sub-th' scope='col'>9</th>
                                <th class='sub-th' scope='col'>TOTAL</th>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </div>
        <?php 
            $x++;
            }
            }
        ?>
```

The output in the browser source, the primary table row HTML is:

```
<div class="collapse">
    <tr data-bs-toggle='collapse' data-bs-target='#609d0993906429612483cf49'>
```

The collapsable row HTML is:

```
<tr id='609d0993906429612483cf49' class='collapse'>                                 
    <td colspan=4>
        <table class='table'>
        ...
```

So it has the `target` and `id` tags populated from the DB.

Comment: Generally I think some browsers don't like ids that start with numbers, so perhaps try prefixing the ids with a letter?

Comment: @johansenja, I think you were right. I copy/pasted code from my working example which did start with characters, and it functioned as expected. thanks for the contribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by @johansenja, starting the div id with character not integer resolved the issue.

Comment: Don't use a integer inside the div id for collapsing divs.